# URL contain Captal Letters || Does it Decrease Ranking?

Tags: php, indexing, web-crawler, ranking, googlebot

I have designed a website in which URLS contain capital letters eg domian.com//Java/Introduction-to-java.php . Does it decrease my website ranking ?  is it fine or do i need to change complete website URL`s. 
if I change all URL`s does google treat them as duplicate because previously indexed pages are in uppercase and current were in lowercase .

my site is completely new i have submitted it to google two days back . i do not have any traffic on my site and no one is linking to my site .I do not want old url with captal letters. Only thing i am worried about google indexed my site so he have old urls... in that case is rename all pages and submit back to google is good option or not .

Comment: You may have issues on Linux systems, which are case sensitive. This depends on what your url references.  For example, is it a file with an extension, or a folder.  Linux will see `Java` and `java` as different paths.  On windows it wont matter, because it's not case sensitive.

Comment: A uri itself is not case sensitive, coding it on the other hand can make it case sensitive. Having different results depending on capital letters may have bots confused and index different results. I am not talking about the googlebot alone, so yes I would assume it will reflect on results however I have not done any research on the matter.

Comment: Just to clarify, linux filesystem is case sensitive.  So as you ( OP ) are using `.php` I have to assume it points to a file.  However if you have a MVC framework you may or may not have issues with casing.  This is because for the most part PHP methods are not case sensitive.

Comment: i have two option now :  option 1 rename all pages to lowercase option 2 use 302 redirest which one is better

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming but SEO.